# How to Optimize images after uploading all images to Wordpress Site?

Tags: wordpress, google-pagespeed

i have uploaded all the images on the wordpress site. There are too many images on the home page. Thus the page loading time is too much. Is there any code for making all the images compressed or optimized, or any plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize uploaded image in wordpress by [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/).

This plugin giving facility for bulk optimization. So you can compress and optimize image very easily. Also this plugin optimize images according proportion. So optimized image not losing quality. It is very best plugin for image optimization.I am currently using this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There are some plugins, of course. From my personal experience, the most reliable is [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/)